# What is preferred .NET 4.5 C# design pattern for windows service which polls DB table record and processes it based on type?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, windows-services, factory

The requirement is to re-write the current windows service app (.net 2.0 with c# to .net 4.5 with design pattern) which is used to poll a db table for pending record, if any pending record, take it process it based on type. There are around 30 different job request possible and we created around 10 classes to serve these job request, some classes serve more than one jobtype

Like AddCreditCard, DeleteCreditCard, UpdateCreditCard can be in 1 class but 3 different job type

Right now code uses switch case to create right object to serve the job. But I see an issue its so static and the ownership is with windows service, I believe there should be a pattern which takes the request like abstract class and based on type it should create object and pass the request to specific class (same as here but in nice pattern)

```
switch (currentRecord.ProcessingType)
        {
        case AddCreditCard:
                {
                    CreditCardProcess ccd = new CreditCardProcess();
                    retVal = ccd.AddCreditCard(currentRecord);
                    if (retVal)
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'C';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = '';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'E';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = 'failed to process';
                    }
                    break;
                }
                #endregion 
        case UpdateCreditCard:
                {
                    CreditCardProcess ccd = new CreditCardProcess();
                    retVal = ccd.UpdateCreditCard(currentRecord);
                      if (retVal)
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'C';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = '';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'E';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = 'failed to process';
                    }
                    break;
                }
        case DeleteCreditCard:
                {
                    CreditCardProcess ccd = new CreditCardProcess();
                    retVal = ccd.DeleteCreditCard(currentRecord);
                      if (retVal)
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'C';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = '';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentRecord.Status = 'E';
                        currentRecord.ErrDesc = 'failed to process';
                    }
                    break;
                }
        case AddACH:

        case DeleteACh:

        case ModifyACH:

        case Authorize:

        case SalesTran:


                #endregion
```

We are using .NET 4.5 with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflections to Match the TypeName with a ClassName, and have generic execute function .
e.g.

```
Interface Actions {
    public execute();
}

class AddCreditCard:Actions
  {
    execute()
      {
          // do DAO for add (etc)
      }
  }

Type typeObj asembly.GetType(currentRecord.ProcessingType);
object actionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeObj);
actionInstance.Execute() ;
```

and something like tht ..

Comment: thanks Blam and Mithun, I moved with the Abstract factory pattern and created a pattern using abstract pattern similar to what Mithun mentiond and it did worked. Blam's should also work but not much information in your comment..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to ccd
You still have the case but encapsulated in ccd

```
public Int RetVal Process (Record currentRecord)
{

}
```